# Common-emitter amplifier not working in LTSpice

Tags: amplifier, ltspice

I'm trying to simulate common-emitter amplifier just like the one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmOX-E_GLIU). However it is not amplifying. What am I doing wrong?

[image: LTSpice picture]

Comment: Always check Vbe,, Missing connection toR2 to base

Comment: Yes, the base divider is not connected.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I didn't see this.